# Did I write this correctly?

Tags: meaning

So I want to say that I read 20 books in Japanese and 20 books in English rather than a total of 20 books. I just want to make sure what I wrote means that and it's clear.

올해는 영어랑 일본어로 써있던 책을 (소설이나 nonfiction) 각각 20권 좀 넘게 읽었어요.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"영어랑 일본어로 써있던 책" sounds more like "books that *had been* written in English and Japanese": it is not clear if you mean books in English/Japanese or books that were *originally written* in English/Japanese and then translated to Korean.

I would simply say "영어랑 일본어 책":

> 올해는 영어랑 일본어 책을 각각 20권 좀 넘게씩 읽었어요.

(Even with 각각, adding -씩 somewhere is highly preferable.  I think Jiho's suggestion is also good.)

Answer (score 2):

It would be more suitable to switch some words.

> 올해는 영어랑 일본어로 써있던 책을 (소설이나 nonfiction) 각각 20권 좀 넘게 읽었어요.

to

> 올해에는 영어랑 일본어로 써있던 책들을 각각 20권 씩을 좀 넘게 읽었어요.